# Using / Extracting spring mvc form field value from jsp into jquery conditional?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I would like to use a spring form value from jsp to be used/ compared inside a jquery so it can redirect the correct handler in Spring MVC.

The form contains a screenState field:

```
<form:form onsubmit="return false;" commandName="helpDeskForm" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="false" method="post">
    ...
    <form:hidden id="screenState" path="screenState" />
    ...
</form:form>
```

in the .jsp

and
the jsp's .js function I would like to get corrected is :

```
$('#btnDone').click(function(event) {
    if( $('#helpDeskForm screenState').val() == 'deleteSentResult')
        changeIframeSrc(searchRequestSentUrl);
    else
        changeIframeSrc(searchRequestUrl);
});
```

where click() should redirect correctly based on which screenState the form returns [sentResult | inboxResult].
The debug failed me on the first case, both cases went to the else{... } , where my web test & my debug on the controller clearly returns the deleteSent.

I am guessing it's the conditional if that's not correct. Can someone point me to the correct conditional for this ?

Thanks vr much all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `#` for id selector here:

```
if( $('#helpDeskForm #screenState').val() == 'deleteSentResult')
//-------------------^---here
```

as ids used to be unique per elem so instead you can shorten it:

```
if( $('#screenState').val() == 'deleteSentResult')
```

Comment: Yes. Thx thats def works and also u don't need the id on <form:hidden path="screenState" /> works equally well. Thx much xxo